# Returning from an array from thread in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I don't know what am I doing wrong in the following function. I am trying to return an array but it Seg Faults at while loop in the compute_average. I am using a structure to initialize the begin and the last word and used in the function "compute_average" You can assume the compute_average function works fine which was already there but I changed the code when using the structure or "first" and "second" value.

```
typedef struct parallel{
unsigned long first, second;
}Parallel;

return final_array;
```

}

Comment: `compute_prime` is defined as `void` yet has a return value.

Comment: I don't believe that's an issue. Check page 9 https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2013/cmsc216/lectures/Week12/ConcurrencyI.pdf

Comment: @jucestain compute_prime returns `void*` which is quite normal for threads

Comment: No, it's defined as void * so it returns a pointer.

Comment: Apart from the answers below, you realize threading buys you absolutely *nothing* in this implementation, right?

Comment: I am actually creating four threads to make the runtime faster. This is just the beginning.

Comment: @user3022651 ok. that makes more sense. I warn you setting up a multi-threaded sieve isn't entirely intuitive. You can't just start in some partition and pull out of the wheel-house with 2,3,5, etc. Its trickier than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument to `pthread_join` is wrong.  You are, in effect, doing this:

```
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

You need to supply the address of a `void *` variable (and technically you should capture the return value of `pthread_join` itself, in case it fails, although here it won't):

```
error = pthread_join(tid, &ary1);
```

If `error==0` after this, `ary1` will contain the value returned from the thread, and `array1 = ary1` will suffice to make it useful (no cast is needed there).

(As [ldav1s noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412973/1256452), the size is wrong too.  You may want to augment the code to return more than just one pointer.  Or you could fill in a data structure supplied by the thread's caller.  [I'm making various guesses here about how you might implement multiple threads, in the end.  The guesses may be wrong. :-) ])

Comment: Now, I get this:
*** glibc detected *** p: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000025b0130 ***
*** glibc detected *** p: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000025b0150 ***

Comment: That's probably from using the wrong size in the main thread.  Given the current code, just use the values from `parallel` the same way as in the compute-thread.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
unsigned long *array1;
...
size = (sizeof(array1)/sizeof(array1[0]));
```

Looks extremely suspicious, unless `size` is supposed to be 1 or 2.  `array1` is a pointer, not an array.

```
pthread_join(tid, ary1);
```

should be:

```
pthread_join(tid, &ary1);
```

If you want to get any data back from `compute_prime` at all.  You also need to "tack on"  some kind of size in the data returned from `compute_prime` to tell you how many elements you've got.

You're also leaking memory allocated in `compute_prime`, better `free(ary1)`.

Comment: I tried: size = (sizeof(*array1)/sizeof(&array1[0])) didn't work.

Comment: @user3022651 the size is (or at least *better be*) `last - first` from your `parallel` structure.